# how to merge AND aggregate 3+ data frames of different lengths and colnames

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, aggregate

I have three data frames of similar structure but with one different column name and different number of rows.

```
> a
        ID count    alpha
1      207     1        1
2      351     1        1
3      372     1        1
4      595     4        1
5      596     1        1
6      652     1        1

> b
        ID count     beta
1      207     1        1
2      351     1        1
3      372     1        1
4     1024     6        1

> c
        ID count     zeta
1      207     4        1
2      351     1        1
3      372     1        1
4      595     2        1
```

I need to make a new data frame with all columns from both (id, count, alpha, beta), while outputting the sum for count. If an ID only shows up in one data frame, it should output 0 in the corresponding column. The desired output is as follows:

```
> abc
        ID count    alpha    beta    zeta
1      207     6        1       1       1
2      351     3        1       1       1
3      372     3        1       1       1
4      595     6        1       0       1
5      596     1        1       0       0
6      652     1        1       0       0
7     1024     6        0       1       0
```

I tried merge() on a and b and got this output:

```
> merge(a, b, by=intersect(names(a),names(b)), all=TRUE, sort=TRUE)
    id count alpha beta
1  207     1     1    1
2  351     1     1    1
3  372     1     1    1
4  595     4     1   NA
5  596     1     1   NA
6  652     1     1   NA
7 1024     6    NA    1
```

I'm OK with 0's being NA's but I have two major problems with this output:

(1) the count columns are not summed

(2) merge() works with just 2 data frames and I actually have a lot more (like 10)

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Why not aggregate as your next step?

Comment: I already lost the information countained in $count, didn't I? *puzzled*

Comment: you can write another merge function: `merge2 <- function(l, ...) Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, ...), l)` where `l` is a list of data frames or matrices. I also agree that you don't need to accomplish everything in one step

Comment: Oh. I see what you're referring to. Maybe use one of the rbind functions that accepts different columns, then aggregate that output.

Comment: Can you add some more details about how you want to deal with the "alpha" and "beta" columns. Are there different columns in the different `data.frame`s? Do some have both "alpha" and "beta"?

Comment: All data frames only have one 'alpha' or 'beta'-type column. The third data frame would have one 'theta' column and the fourth data frame would have one 'zeta' column and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this:

1. Create a `list` of the relevant `data.frame`s (as easy as putting them all in `list()`.
2. Use `rbindlist` (or one of the other enhanced `rbind` function that lets you bind datasets together by rows *even if the columns are different*--see "plyr" and "dplyr" for other common alternatives to `rbindlist`).

Here, I've used `rbindlist` from "data.table".

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(a, b, c), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)[
  , lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = ID]
#      ID count alpha beta zeta
# 1:  207     6     1    1    1
# 2:  351     3     1    1    1
# 3:  372     3     1    1    1
# 4:  595     6     1    0    1
# 5:  596     1     1    0    0
# 6:  652     1     1    0    0
# 7: 1024     6     0    1    0
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly how you want to deal with the "alpha", "beta", ... columns. I've just summed everything.

---

Sample data used in this answer:

```
a <- structure(list(
  ID = c(207L, 351L, 372L, 595L, 596L, 652L), 
  count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L), 
  alpha = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
  .Names = c("ID", "count", "alpha"), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
b <- structure(list(
  ID = c(207L, 351L, 372L, 1024L), 
  count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 6L), beta = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
  .Names = c("ID", "count", "beta"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
c <- structure(list(
  ID = c(207L, 351L, 372L, 595L), 
  count = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L), zeta = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
  .Names = c("ID", "count", "zeta"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `dplyr` in stages.

Given data:

```
dfA <- data.frame(c(207, 351, 372, 595, 596, 652), c(1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1), rep(1, 6))
names(dfA) <- c('ID', 'count', 'alpha')
dfB <- data.frame(c(207, 351, 372, 1024), c(1, 1, 1, 6), rep(1, 4))
names(dfB) <- c('ID', 'count', 'beta')
dfC <- data.frame(c(207, 351, 372, 595), c(4, 1, 1, 2), rep(1, 4))
names(dfC) <- c('ID', 'count', 'zeta')
```

The following, while somewhat ugly, will work:

```
library(dplyr)
dfT <- bind_rows(dfA, dfB, dfC)
df_1 <- dfT %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(sum(count))
df_F <- data.frame(df_1, as.numeric(df_i$ID %in% dfA$ID), as.numeric(df_i$ID %in% dfB$ID), as.numeric(df_i$ID %in% dfC$ID))
names(df_F) <- c("ID", "count", "alpha", "beta", "zeta")

> df_F
    ID count alpha beta zeta
1  207     6     1    1    1
2  351     3     1    1    1
3  372     3     1    1    1
4  595     6     1    0    1
5  596     1     1    0    0
6  652     1     1    0    0
7 1024     6     0    1    0
```

Comment: You save a lot of typing by `bind_rows(dfA, dfB, dfC) %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(.,na.rm=TRUE)))`

Comment: @Khashaa, yes you do; a cleaner call, certainly. I need to brush up in my `_each`-fu it seems. Thank you.